# Open Graph tags in XHTML - "property" not known

Tags: facebook, properties, xhtml, facebook-opengraph, rdfa

after several hours of researching I really need your help.

I simply want to define the preview picture, when I post the website-url on facebook. I already added these meta properties to my website:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="image.png" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Website" />
```

This is my Doctype Specification:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

However, the attribute "property" does not exist. Yes, this is not new to xhtml. So I looked in older threads and extended the Doctype with RDFa, so now it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0">
```

But this still doesn't work!

When I use the Open Graph Object Debugger from Facebook, it says:
"Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties", and it shows many random images which are included in my website, but none of them are usable as preview picture.

I am really desperate and would greatly appreciate your help!

Edit: Can anybody help please :P